Hyperplane cutting hyperball into pieces
I never studied multidimensional geometry, and I have absolutely zero intuition about it, so I may be very wrong about the following (maybe it doesn't even make sense?):

The straight-line, a one-dimensional shape, cuts the disk, a two-dimensional shape, in at max two pieces.
The plane, a two-dimensional shape, cuts the ball, a three-dimensional shape, in at max two pieces.

I want to know if the following is true:

The hyperplane of n dimensions cuts the hyperball of n+1 dimensions in at max two pieces.


Yes.$\mathstrut$
